# Symbolic matrices are not expanded

Tags: matrix, symbolic, tensors

I have defined two symbolic matrices and I am performing several operations.

```
$Assumptions = (Nf | k) ∈ Integers && 0 < k < Nf && (Hp | Hq) ∈ Matrices[{Nb, Ub}]
Hk = Hp + (k/Nf) (Hq - Hp) 
Rk = ConjugateTranspose[Hk].Hk
```

My questions are:

1. How can I get $(A+B)^H = A^H + B^H$? My `Hk` is a sum of two matrices, in `Rk`, there is a Hermitian operation.
2. How can I get $(A_1+B_1).(A_2+B_2)=A_1 \, A_2 + A_1 \, B_2 + B_1 \, A_2 + B_1\,B_2$? My `Rk` is a multiplication of two expressions.

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

I think [`TensorExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorExpand) is the tool for this job. For your second example:

```
TensorExpand[(A1 + B1) . (A2 + B2)]
```

> A1.A2 + A1.B2 + B1.A2 + B1.B2

On the other hand, for your first example:

```
TensorExpand[ConjugateTranspose[A+B]]
```

> ConjugateTranspose[A + B, {2, 1}]

it doesn't work. I think it's worth reporting this to support. One possible workaround is:

```
Options[ctExpand] = Options[TensorExpand];

ctExpand[e_, opts:OptionsPattern[]] := TensorExpand[
    Conjugate @ TensorExpand[
        Conjugate @ e,
        opts
    ],
    opts
]
```

Then:

```
ctExpand @ ConjugateTranspose[A + B]
```

> ConjugateTranspose[A, {2, 1}] + ConjugateTranspose[B, {2, 1}]

For your more complicated example:

```
ctExpand[Rk]
```

> ConjugateTranspose[Hp, {2, 1}].Hp - (
>    k ConjugateTranspose[Hp, {2, 1}].Hp)/Nf - (
>    Conjugate[k] ConjugateTranspose[Hp, {2, 1}].Hp)/Conjugate[Nf] + (
>    k Conjugate[k] ConjugateTranspose[Hp, {2, 1}].Hp)/(Nf Conjugate[Nf]) + (
>    k ConjugateTranspose[Hp, {2, 1}].Hq)/Nf - (
>    k Conjugate[k] ConjugateTranspose[Hp, {2, 1}].Hq)/(Nf Conjugate[Nf]) + (
>    Conjugate[k] ConjugateTranspose[Hq, {2, 1}].Hp)/Conjugate[Nf] - (
>    k Conjugate[k] ConjugateTranspose[Hq, {2, 1}].Hp)/(Nf Conjugate[Nf]) + (
>    k Conjugate[k] ConjugateTranspose[Hq, {2, 1}].Hq)/(Nf Conjugate[Nf])

The above is a bit difficult to read, so here is a more readable version:

```
(res /. ConjugateTranspose[a_, {2, 1}] -> ConjugateTranspose[a]) //TeXForm
```

> $-\frac{k k^* \operatorname{Hp}^{\dagger }.\operatorname{Hq}}{\operatorname{Nf} \operatorname{Nf}^*}-\frac{k k^*
>    \operatorname{Hq}^{\dagger }.\operatorname{Hp}}{\operatorname{Nf} \operatorname{Nf}^*}+\frac{k^*
>    \operatorname{Hq}^{\dagger }.\operatorname{Hp}}{\operatorname{Nf}^*}+\frac{k k^* \operatorname{Hp}^{\dagger
>    }.\operatorname{Hp}}{\operatorname{Nf} \operatorname{Nf}^*}-\frac{k^* \operatorname{Hp}^{\dagger
>    }.\operatorname{Hp}}{\operatorname{Nf}^*}+\frac{k k^* \operatorname{Hq}^{\dagger
>    }.\operatorname{Hq}}{\operatorname{Nf} \operatorname{Nf}^*}+\frac{k \operatorname{Hp}^{\dagger
>    }.\operatorname{Hq}}{\operatorname{Nf}}-\frac{k \operatorname{Hp}^{\dagger
>    }.\operatorname{Hp}}{\operatorname{Nf}}+\operatorname{Hp}^{\dagger }.\operatorname{Hp}$